# Generating IDs, based on what number is not in use as an ID of other comment

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm making this algorithm that should generate new ID for newly created comment. ID should be unique, so I made several loops, that iterate over existing comment's IDs and check if a number is already in use as a ID on other comment.

It's hard to explain and my brain melts as I'm trying to figure it out, so here is the code. It doesn't work right now. Any ideas?

comments is an array full of objects. Each object has ID property which value is a number.

```
var newId;
var possibleId = -1;
while (!newId) {
  possibleId++
  for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){
    if(state.comments[i]){
      if (comments[i].id !== possibleId){
        if (i === comments.length - 1){
          newId = possibleId
          break
        }
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the IDs have to be numbers? I'd suggest using a GUID string, and there are several GUID/UUID JavaScript generator libraries floating around on Github and other places. A web search will quickly turn up some nice resources.

Comment: `var newId=null,possibleId=0,commentIDs=state.comments.map(function(comment){return comment.id});while(newId===null){newId=commentIDs.indexOf(++possibleId)>-1 ? null : possibleId;}`

Comment: since you don't seem worried about database concurrency why not take current utc time as timestamp

Answer (score 2):

solution using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var nextId =  comments.reduce(a,c){
     return Math.max(a, c.id);
},0) +1;
```

just get highest current and add one

Comment: This works.. though It doesn't make use of replacing deleted IDs.

Comment: why do you even need to fill holes?

Answer (score 0):

```
var possibleId = 0;
var loop = true;
var idExists = false;

while (loop) {
for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){ 
   if (possibleId === comments[i]) {
        idExists = true;
    }
}

if (!idExists) {
 loop = false;
 newId = possibleID;
}
else {
possibleId++;
idExists = false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var possibleId;
var loop;
var idExists;

init();

function init () {
    possibleId = 0;
    loop = true;
    idExists = false;
}

while (loop) {
for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){ 
   if (possibleId === comments[i]) {
        idExists = true;
    }
}

if (!idExists) {
 loop = false;
 newId = possibleID;
}
else {
possibleId++;
idExists = false;
}

}
```